# Call child method from base method without virtual or references

Tags: c++

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void g() {std::cout << "Call from A" << std::endl;}
    void f() {g();}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void g() {std::cout << "Call from B" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.f(); // "Call from A" 
}
```

If I make `A::g()` virtual, it outputs "Call from B".

I always understood "virtual" useful when we want an *interface* to allow polymorphism, say `A *a = new B(); a->f()`, but this example indicates that `virtual` is also required in this situation. My understanding of this example is that the call `g()` on `A::f` is formally equivalent to `this->g()`, and this is a pointer.

However, this is not what I really wanted: in my real example, I have a general template class A with a general method `A::simulate` (say `A::f`), that uses different methods (say `A::g()`), some of which are overwritten by subclass (say `B`). What I wanted was to have the method `A::simulate` in such a way that the code would be compiled in the subclasses of A as if it has been defined on the subclasses so I don't have the same logic coded multiple-times. How can I do this?

This is because my interface will not require polymorphism because the user will always need to compile the code (i.e. it is header only).

Comment: Make your base class a CRTP template class.

Comment: Can you explain in different words the problem if you make A::g() virtual?

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin: why should I make A::g() virtual? For me, polymorphism or not is part of the interface I'm producing. Since I don't see how polymorphism helps *in my specific use case*, I don't have a compelling reason to add it. I wanted to know if I *really* needed to add it because of the language I'm using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply make your base class a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (as you've mentioned it's already a templated class anyway):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
class A {
public:
    void g() {std::cout << "Call from A" << std::endl;}
    void f() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->g();}
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Call g() from Derived
};

class B : public A<B> {
public:
    void g() {std::cout << "Call from B" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.f(); // "Call from B" 
}
```

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Yes, it's useful for a number of use cases (mixin interfaces, policy based desgns, etc.). Especially useful for embedded designs, where you want to avoid additional overhead introduced with vtables, and well know you won't need runtime configurations (but merely configure your actually available hardware components at compile time).